# Taking complex input from a file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am working on a program where i have to find if a point lies inside a circle and data for which is given by user. I have prepared my algorithm but i am struggling to quantify the data given by the user to a particular container like list or a dictionary. It has to be in the format like below and is passed via a file as a parameter.

```
Center: (2.12, -3.48); Radius: 17.22; Point: (16.21, -5)
```

I tried this code below

```
from sys import argv

file_name = argv[1]
fp = open(file_name,'r+')

contents = [line.strip('\n') for line in fp]
content = [item.split(' ') for item in contents]

#content = fp.read().split(';') #commented

print (contents, '\n' , content)
```

Output is:-

```
['Center: (2.12, -3.48); Radius: 17.22; Point: (16.21, -5)']
[['Center:', '(2.12', '-3.48);', 'Radius:', '17.22;', 'Point:', '(16.21,', '-5)']
```

So, clearly i am nowhere near to get those integer values to solve the problem. Also due to addition of ';' ':' ',' have further made the situation more complex.

What approach should i try to quantify each term separately. Is there any way if i can get only those Integer values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is regular, you can just use regular expressions like so:

```
import re
data = "Center: (2.12, -3.48); Radius: 17.22; Point: (16.21, -5)"
result = re.search('Center: \(([-0-9\.]+), ([-0-9\.]+)\); Radius: ([-0-9\.]+); Point: \(([-0-9\.]+), ([-0-9\.]+)\)', data)
center_x, center_y, radius, point_x, point_y = map(float, result.groups())
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked. It didn't clicked to me that i can use regular expression also. Thanks @Anonymous

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `eval`, as suggested by lolopop's answer. [`eval` is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Instead use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

An example:

```
import ast

input_line = "Center: (2.12, -3.48); Radius: 17.22; Point: (16.21, -5)"

center, radius, point = input_line.split(";")
center = ast.literal_eval(center.split(":")[1].strip())
radius = ast.literal_eval(radius.split(":")[1].strip())
point = ast.literal_eval(point.split(":")[1].strip())

print center, radius, point
```

---

This outputs:

```
(2.12, -3.48) 17.22 (16.21, -5)
```

`center` is the first tuple. `radius` is the single value. `point` is the last tuple.

---

This is splitting the string at the semicolon (`;`) between each value. The value of `center` after this split is:

```
Center: (2.12, -3.48)
```

The other values look similar. Next, we utilize `literal_eval` on the second portion of each of those splits by utilizing a split on the colon (`:`). We also strip leading and trailing spaces, because there is a space between the colon and the value. If don't do this, we get an IndentionException.

Answer (score 0):

What about `.split('; ')` and `eval` since the data is pretty much in python form? It can be dangerous but if you want to get it quick and can rely on the input that's the easy way.

Obviously, the **right** way of doing it is using regex, available via `import re`:

```
import re
match = re.match("Center: \(([0-9\.]*), ([0-9\.]*)\); Radius: ([0-9\.]); Point: \(([0-9\.]*), ([0-9\.]*)\)", line)
```

and then

```
point = (match.group(0), match.group(1))
```

etc.

Not sure about the regex pattern, haven't tested it. Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Thanks @lolopop, i tried the way anonymous described in above comments, it worked.